# Declaration of array of objects - null value

Tags: java, declaration

I have two-dimensional array

```
protected MyClass[][] myArray;
```

in constructor I have this

```
this.myArray= new MyClass[20][20];
```

Now, without inicialization (aka this.myArray[2][2] = new MyClass(par0, par1);)
the value of this.myArray[2][2] is "null".

Is this guaranteed? And where can I read more about this subject? (for primitive types like int or boolean too)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's guaranteed. Array values are initialized with null (for objects), 0 (for numeric primitives) and false (for boolean primitives), just like fields.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6-100:

> Space is allocated for a new array of that length. If there is insufficient space to allocate the array, evaluation of the array initializer completes abruptly by throwing an OutOfMemoryError. Otherwise, a one-dimensional array is created of the specified length, and **each component of the array is initialized to its default value (§4.12.5)**.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Thanks, I could not find this on oracle.com.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This behavior is guaranteed. The default value of an `Object` is null. Therefore the default values for an array of `Objects` is also null so every element in the array needs to be instantiated. See *Default Values* in [Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is guaranteed. Every type has a default initialization value:

- numeric primitives = 0
- boolean = false
- all Objects = null